# How can I use the iPhones native weather app information

Tags: xcode5

I wanted to add the current temp & condition to my app, but I want it to match the native weather app info, is there a way I can use the info from the native weather app? (IOS7 Xcode 5).
Thanks.

Comment: No, there isn't. But, I believe the weather app is powered by Yahoo, in which case you could use their API to get the same information. http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to get the data from the same source as the native weather app if you want it to match. Apple doesn't provide any APIs to get the weather information. It appears that Apple uses Yahoo! for their weather information, so you'll have to look at the APIs from Yahoo! to retrieve it yourself.

Comment: There is a tweak in the jailbreak community that pulls the info direct from the phone's native weather app & stores it in an xml file, so it can be done.

Comment: If you're willing to jailbreak your device, and develop your apps solely for jailbreak devices, then you can do quite a bit more than what Apple currently allows. The question is whether limiting yourself to jailbreak devices is worth having your app show exactly the same weather information as Apple's app. But with Yahoo's APIs, it shouldn't even be necessary to jailbreak, anyway, to get the same information.

Comment: Hi Gavin, My device is already jailbroken, my app is just for me and a few friends, I didn't want to code more calls to the net to get location and weather info when it's already in the phone. Do you know exactly where I can pull this info from the stock weather app? Thanks.

Comment: @user2253720 Sorry, not sure where you would look to find it. But if you search online you might be able to find something if you include jailbreak in the search. I don't have a jailbroken device currently.